# Converting to PDO, Getting '' in Quoted $_POST inserts into Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, quote

I'm sure this is me making some obvious mistake, but I'm very new to PHP/mySQL, and converting a simple user registration system to PDO for security. I've read through the docs and many threads, but still beating my head against a wall.

Simple HTML form posts an email address, php script is connecting fine to my database via PDO and I'm catching the email address here:

```
$email = $db->quote($_POST["email"]);

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userlogin (email) VALUES (:email)");

$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
```

Expected database insert (or echo): name@email.com
Actual database insert (or echo): 'name@email.com'

Seems like something so simple, but obviously I am missing a basic concept here. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems like something so simple,

yes. take out the first line and keep it this way:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userlogin (email) VALUES (:email)");
$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: My understanding is that the quote is an important step to guard against SQL injections. Maybe that's the part I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Try to follow any tutorial on PDO and see how they do it.

Comment: This answer can help you to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks/8265319#8265319

Comment: Exactly the explanation this I needed. Thanks for helping us beginners!